# PyQt “Not responding”

Tags: python, selenium, pyqt

I'm using Selenium with Python. I'm getting a message in widows Python, when the button is clicked:

> Not responding in widows Python
>   [image: Not responding in widows Python]
>    I have the following script:

####file:qu

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s
#####
try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(324, 200, 111, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 240, 151, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.log)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.log2)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton_2", None))
    def log(self):############################
            from qf import functon 
            n=functon()
            n.log1()
    def log2(self):
            from qf import functon 
            n=functon()
            n.log3()
```

###file:qm

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from qu import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

file:qf

```
from   selenium import webdriver
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from qu import Ui_MainWindow


class functon ():
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        self.parent=parent


    def log1(self):
            browser =webdriver.Firefox()
            browser.get( "http://google.com" )

    def log3(self):        
            text =unicode(self.lineEdit.text())
            print text
```

[“Not responding”  in Python.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWvy5.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, You main GUI is not frozen at all but only for the time `log` gets executed and returns control to the main GUI, as you are not implementing any sort of threading mechanism in your application.

So as a solution, you need to *thread* `log` method to not block your main GUI, using `threading` module, the following is a generic way, you need to read more about [`threading`](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/#module-threading):

1 - `import threading` in your `qu.py` file

2 - Define this method in `qu.py` as well:

```
def launch_Selenium_Thread(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.log)
        t.start()
```

3 - Change the `connect` method of `pushButton` to:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.launch_Selenium_Thread)
```

4 -Add in `qf.py` `log3` method, `txt` parameter:

```
def log3(self, txt):        
        text =unicode(txt)
        print text
```

5 - Finally fix in `qu.py` `log2` method:

```
def log2(self):
            from qf import functon 
            n=functon()
            txt = self.lineEdit.text()
            n.log3(txt)
```

Comment: So wonderful, thanks very much.East or west, "Iron Fist" is the best.

Comment: @AhmadAli...Glad to be of Help..:)