# AttributeError: 'class_c' object has no attribute 'lineEdit'

Tags: python, user-interface, methods

I have a gui application

1. I put text into text box and then click on the pushButton,
2. The function `callprinttext()`  in the `moduel_b.py` be called.
3. The function `callprinttext()` is calling method `printtext()`  in the `moduel_c.py`

but I have an error:

```
 AttributeError: 'class_c' object has no attribute 'lineEdit'
```

can anyone help me with `class_c`?
Here's the code for that:

`module_c.py`

```
class class_c (object):
     def __init__(self, parent=None):
       self.parent=parent

 ### I want a fix for error here
     def printtext (self):
          t=unicode(self.lineEdit.text()) 
          print t
```

`module_b.py`

```
import sys
from GUI import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class calss_b (object):
     def __init__(self, parent=None):
      pass

     def callprinttext (self):
         from module_c import class_c
         instance_c=class_c()
         instance_c.printtext()
```

`main.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from GUI import Ui_MainWindow
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        from module_b import calss_b
        global instance_b
        instance_b=calss_b(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), instance_b.callprinttext )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    global myapp
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

GUI

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    try:
        _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
    except AttributeError:
        def _fromUtf8(s):
            return s
    try:
        _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
        def _translate(context, text, disambig):
            return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
    except AttributeError:
        def _translate(context, text, disambig):
            return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)
    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()
            MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
            MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
            self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
            self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 110, 75, 23))
            self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
            self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 240, 151, 20))
            self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
            self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
            self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
            MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
            self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
            self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
            MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None))
```

Comment: Well, `class_c` *doesn't* have a `lineEdit` attribite. What makes you think it does?

Comment: I want divide the project into several parts.

Comment: So I assume you want to pass what's in `lineEdit` as text to `printtext ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way to do it is using a call back method, this way:

In `main.py`

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.call_back)

def call_back(self):
    txt = str(self.ui.lineEdit.text()) #lineEdit.text() returns QString Object so we need to convert it to String object
    instance_b.callprinttext(txt)
```

Then in your `calss_b` method:

```
def callprinttext (self, txt):
    from module_c import class_c
    instance_c=class_c()
    instance_c.printtext(txt)
```

And Finally in your `class_c` method:

```
def printtext (self, txt):
    t=unicode(txt) 
    print t
```

**EDIT :**

If you don't want to add any call back method, then do it using `lambda`, this way:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), \
                       lambda: instance_b.callprinttext(self.ui.lineEdit.text()))
```

And there is no need for `call_back`

Comment: AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'lineEdit'

Comment: and ,I do not want Add functions in the main.py

Comment: My target: Reduce the number of functions in main.py

Comment: I need devote main.py for limited functions (signal and run application),

Comment: @AhmadAli...did you write something in `lineEdit` before you press the `pushButton`?..

Comment: @AhmadAli...`lineEdit.text()` returns `QString`, so had to convert it to `string` using `str()`...check my updated answer

Comment: The same problem, lines empty

Comment: @AhmadAli...Check again...this should work as I've test it myself.

Comment: NICE, GOOD JOB , THANKS VERY MUCH.

Comment: Can you help me here ??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386561/pyqt-not-responding

Comment: @AhmadAli...Check my answer ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386561/pyqt-not-responding/34484638#34484638

Comment: If I had lineEdit2 ,lineEdit3 .....How do I modify the last  code?   QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), \
                       lambda: instance_b.callprinttext(self.ui.lineEdit.text()))

Comment: Can you explain more...or add it to your question?

Comment: I add it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499525/how-do-i-call-an-gui-object-or-more-from-main-class

Comment: @ Iron Fist I am can not add more questions>> Message from stackoverflow.com :(you have reached your question limit) , can u help me??

Comment: @AhmadAli...What's your issue this time?

Comment: @ Iron Fist .. Message from stackoverflow.com : You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: @AhmadAli...It means you have asked many questions....may be you can wait for some time to be able to Post Questions again.

Comment: @ Iron Fist    Message :  Users who are banned from asking questions see the following error message when trying to post a new question:

We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.
Question bans do not affect other privileges, such as commenting or voting, and there is no indication to the rest of the community that a particular user has been banned.

How can I get out of a question ban?

The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received.

Comment: @AhmadAli...It means you've asked too many questions more than your contributions as answers to SO community...so you need to answers more questions than asking them...

Comment: @ Iron Fist....  Can you review my questions and Fix the problem? I need your help to ask you  more question about bython.