# How do I call an GUI object or more from main class

Tags: python, lambda, pyqt4, call, instance

I have a gui application

1. I put text into text box1, text box2,and then click on the `pushButton`,
2. The function `return_text_username ()` in the `moduel_b.py` be called.
   Now I can call one instance by `lambda1` function and use it in `class_b`, but I can not call two instants when I click on the `pushbutton`.

**A-  I want add `lineEdit_2`  into lambda method  in `main.py` or add `instance_lambda2_password` into  `connect` method.

**B- I want to edit `return_printtext_password (self, txt)` in the `moduel_b.py` to print and return password.

Can anyone help me?
Here's the code for that :

`main.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from GUI import Ui_MainWindow
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        from module_b import calss_b
        global instance_b
        instance_b=calss_b(self)
        instance_lambda1_username=lambda: instance_b.return_text_username(self.ui.lineEdit.text())##I want to add lineEdit_2 
        instance_lambda2_password=lambda: instance_b.printtext2(self.ui.lineEdit_2.text())
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), \
        instance_lambda1_username)## Or add instance_lambda2_password here.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    global myapp
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`module_b.py`

```
import sys
from GUI import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class calss_b (object):
     def __init__(self, parent=None):
      pass


     def return_text_username (self, txt):
        username=unicode(txt) 
        print username  
        return username 

      ## I want print password and return it.   
     def return_printtext_password (self, txt):
        password=unicode(txt) 
        print password   
        return password
```

Comment: So Basically, you want to connect `pushButton` `clicked` signal to two methods (`return_text_username` and `return_printtext_password`) ?

Comment: @Iron Fist yes >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Comment: But that means passing to each of them (`return_text_username` and `return_printtext_password`) different texts from `self.lineEdit1` and `self.lineEdit2` , right?

Comment: @Iron Fist >>> Of course

Comment: Why not combining `return_text_username` and `return_printtext_password` into one method and you can return a tuple `return username, password` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define `lambda` function for each `slot`, instead group them into one and pass it to your `connect` method, this way:

```
txt1 = self.ui.lineEdit.text #Method reference not Method call
txt2 = self.ui.lineEdit2.text 
mySlot = lambda : (instance_b.return_text_username(txt1()), instance_b.return_printtext_password(txt2()))# Passed to lambda method call this time
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),  mySlot)
```

As for Point-B, I think you've already managed to do it,

```
 def return_text_username (self, txt):
     username=unicode(txt) 
     print username  
     return username
```

Comment: No pblm @AhmadAli .. :)

Comment: What the better way to write codes when we have table and so much of  tx3,txt4,txt5......txt 50  ???

Comment: @AhmadAli...not clear, can you Post is as a question with details to make it clear?

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517084/i-can-not-add-many-values-in-one-function