# I can not add many values in one function

Tags: python, function, instance

I have a gui application

1. I put text into text box1, text box2,………… text box70 ,and then click on the `pushButton`,
2. The function `return_text ()` in the `module_b.py` be called. Now I can call one instance by `lambda1` function and use it in `class_b`, but I can not call 70 instances when I click on the `pushbutton`.

**A- I want add lineEdit_1 ,  lineEdit_2  ….. lineEdit_70  into `lambda` method in `main.py`

**B- I want to edit `(return_text (self, txt))` and `(table2 (self, txt) )` in the `module_b.py` to print and return values from . `student1` to `student70`

Can anyone help me? Here's the code for that :

`main.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from GUI import Ui_MainWindow
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        from module_b import calss_b
        global instance_b
        instance_b=calss_b(self)
        txt1 = self.ui.lineEdit.text #Method reference not Method call
        txt2 = self.ui.lineEdit2.text 
        mySlot = lambda : (instance_b.return_text_username(txt1()) 
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),mySlot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    global myapp
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`module_b.py`

```
import sys
from GUI import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class calss_b (object):
     def __init__(self, parent=None):
      pass


     def return_text (self, txt):
  ####  global student1, student2 , student3………. Student70
        student1=unicode(txt) 
        return first_student
#####   ….
        …
        return 70

    def table2 (self, txt):
        print student1
        print 2
#####   ….
        …
        print 70
```

Comment: So you want to sent to `return_text` all texts from the 70 `lineEdit` and then `return` them at once?

Comment: Can you not just pass a list of students to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can thing of, is to collect all the `lineEdit` into a list and pass it to `return_text` method then call `text()` method in each iteration, this way:

```
number_of_line_Edit = 70
txt = [getattr(self.ui,'lineEdit{0}'.format(i)) for i in range(1,number_of_line_Edit+1)] #This will collect all lineEdit(s) reference so we can call there methods in return_text method
mySlot = lambda :instance_b.return_text(txt)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),  mySlot)
```

Then in `return_text` and `table2` methods of `module_b.py` :

```
def return_text(self, lineEdit_list):
    my_text_list = []
    for t in lineEdit_list:
        txt = unicode(t.text())
        self.table2(txt)
        my_text_list.append(txt)
     #print my_text_list for checking purpose
     return my_text_list


## I want print password and return it.   
def table2(self, my_txt):
    print my_txt
```

Note that `my_text_list` list will be always reset to empty list every time `return_text` method is called, where it will lose all texts of `lineEdit`(s) of previous call.

Comment: Glad to be of help @AhmadAli

Comment: <<<<<<< Hi ...Can you help  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640545/how-can-i-get-values-in-different-ranges-of-cells