# How can i get values in different ranges of cells?

Tags: python, excel, list, cell

I am using  `xlwt` with Python to get some data from something and writing it in an `xls` file,but I need to get outputs in different ranges of cells.
I have code like this:-

```
 #Here's the code for that :
    import xlwt
    from tempfile import TemporaryFile
    book = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet1 = book.add_sheet('sheet1')

    a=[1,2,3,4,5]
    b=[6,7,8,9,10]
    c=[2,3,4,5,6]
    data = [a,b,c]
    for row, array in enumerate(data):
        for col, value in enumerate(array):
            sheet1.write(row, col, value)
    name = "table.xls"
    book.save(name)
    book.save(TemporaryFile())
```

Output("table.xls"):

```
#Output
    *   A   B   C   D   E

    1   1   2   3   4   5

    2   6   7   8   9   10

    3   2   3   4   5   6
```

But I want something like this:

```
# I want the values in different ranges of cells

*   A   B   C   D   E    F   G   H   I

1   1       6       2   3    4   5   6

2   2       7

3   3       8

4   4       9

5   5      10
```

Can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: I see you want it first and second lists as columns and third list as row...is that correct?

Comment: @ Iron Fist ... I need your help here too  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676285/how-can-i-create-duplicate-sheets-from-sheet1-then-input-list-data-in-those-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one of the easiest solution is to use [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.izip_longest) from `itertools` module, this way:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b=[6,7,8,9,10]
>>> c=[2,3,4,5,6]
>>> c_ = [[x] for x in c]
>>> c_
[[2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
>>> data = list(izip_longest(a,[],b,[],*c_, fillvalue=''))
>>> for i in data:
    l = []
    for j in i:
        l.append(j)
    print l

[1, '', 6, '', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, '', 7, '', '', '', '', '', '']
[3, '', 8, '', '', '', '', '', '']
[4, '', 9, '', '', '', '', '', '']
[5, '', 10, '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Now you can easily write it to your excel file:

```
for row, array in enumerate(data):
    for col, value in enumerate(array):
        sheet1.write(row, col, value)
```

I assumed you are using Python2

Comment: @JehanMazen .. I assume you can use `itertools` module, right?

Comment: Good job.. Thank you @Iron Fist

Comment: @JehanMazen .. no pblm

Comment: Hi I need help here>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967007/cannot-set-parent-new-parent-is-in-a-different-thread