# How can I create duplicate sheets from sheet1,Then input list (data ) in those sheets?

Tags: python, excel, list

I am using `xlwt` and `xlrd`  with Python to get some data from something and writing it into an `xls` file, but I need to get outputs in different sheets.
I want to create (N) number of duplicate copies of sheet1, then input list of (data) in those sheets(sheet2,sheet3,...sheetN)

I have code like this:-

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import easyxf
from xlutils.copy import copy

data = [['2008','2009','2011'],['Jan','Feb','Feb'],[100,200,300]]

##Here ...I want creat (N) number of duplicate copies of sheet1
rb = open_workbook('this1.xls')
rs = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
wb = copy(rb)
ws = wb.get_sheet(0)



##Here  I want to do loop to input (data) in  sheets (sheet2,sheet3,...sheetN) .
for i,row in enumerate(data):
      for j,cell in enumerate(row):
         ws.write(j,i,cell)
wb.save('outlines.xls')
```

Output("outlines.xls"):

## Output (sheet1)

```
*   A        B       C   

1   2008    Jan    100


2   2009    Feb    200


3   2011    Feb    300
```

But I want Output like this:

```
sheet (2):
*   A           

1   2008    

2   2009    

3   2011          

sheet (3):
*    A           

1   Jan

2   Feb 

3   Feb 

sheet (N):
-
-
-
```

[image: sheet1]

[image: sheet2]

[image: sheet3]

Comment: I don't understand...are `sheet2`...`sheetN` supposed to be exact copies of `sheet1`?

Comment: @Iron Fist yes ,, sheet2...sheetN supposed to be exact copies of sheet1 , but that before input [data] .

Comment: Ok..but what does `sheet1` has initially before input[data] to make a copies of it..`sheet2`...`sheetN`?...because in your question, I see different contents of `sheet2`, `sheet3`...etc..so they don't look duplicate of something original?

Comment: sheet1  ..It's sheet contain old data and coordinated such as table.We can add new data for sheet2,.3,4,...

Comment: I need sheet1 as design.

Comment: Sorry but it is still not clear to me...

Comment: @Iron Fist   Now I have sheet1:

I need the following:

1-creat sheet2,sheet3,...sheetn

2-Copy old contents of the sheet1 to sheet2,sheet3,...sheetn

3-input list[data] in COL(A1) of sheet2,sheet3,...sheetn

Comment: so `data` is not actually a list of three items, it's an n element lists?

Comment: @Iron Fist Yes it's an n element lists

Comment: @Iron Fist  Can you help me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967007/how-can-i-make-new-thread-in-python